# React Router v4 not navigating to historical pages using back/forward buttons

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using `react-router-dom: v4.1.1`, and this is my router code:

```
var ReactRouter = require('react-router-dom');
var Router = ReactRouter.BrowserRouter;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Switch = ReactRouter.Switch;
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.BrowserHistory;

  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <div className='container'>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Home
      {...props} // for router history and all that.
      rebase={rebase}
      items={this.state.items}
      user={this.state.currentUser}
      userData={this.state.currentUserData}/>} />
    <Route path='/browse' render={() => <Browse items={_.values(this.state.items)}/>} />
    <Route render={function () {
      return <p>Not Found</p>
    }} />
  </Switch>
</div>
  </Router>
```

In the `Home` component I have a button which, when clicked, adds a new url to the history: `this.props.history.push('/?p=' + hash)` where `hash` is simply something like `f9ojy`. This 'works' in the sense that the URL in the window is updated to the new hash, but when I click 'back' or 'forward' there's no change in the displayed page.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the Reactiflux discord channel; in `componentDidUpdate` I can check the previous `this.props.location.search` and compare it against the current one. If it's not the same I have a function which resets the UI based on the current parameter.